# How do I get both the callback function arguments and the function return value outside of the function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise, callback

For a function that takes a callback function as an argument but also has a return value, can I get both the callback function argument and the function return value outside the function?

Here is a concrete example. Suppose we have `func_a` as follows.

```
function func_a(callback:(arg:string)=>void){
  callback("callback arg")
  return "func_a return"
}
```

My question is, is it possible to extract both the callback function argument,`"callback arg"` and the function return value `"func_a return"` outside `func_a`?

As shown in the following code, `Promise` and `then` can be used to retrieve the arguments of the callback function, but not the return value of `func_a`.

```
new Promise<string>(
  (resolve)=>{
    const func_a_return=func_a((arg)=>resolve(arg))
  }
).then((arg)=>{console.log(arg)})
```

This question about [`onSnapshot` of firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) because I wanted to retrieve both the callback function argument `snapshot` and the function return value `unsubscribe` outside `onSnapshot`.

Comment: The first code example (with `func_a`) is not representative for your question, as the callback is not called asynchronously.

Comment: Do you want to know how to get types of argument and return type?

Comment: I realized a big mistake, the callback function of `onSnapshot` is called on every firestore update so I should not resolve in the callback function. I should use `useState` or create custom hooks if I want to componentize it.

Answer (score 1):

> This question about `onSnapshot` of firestore because I wanted to retrieve both the callback function argument snapshot and the function return value unsubscribe outside onSnapshot.

Contrary to the example of `func_a`, `onSnapshot` will not call the callback synchronously, which means that *first* `onSnapshot` returns the unsubscribe function, and only when the execution reaches an empty call stack, will the callback get a chance to run.

This means, that the unsubscribe function will be available to you in the callback function, so you can do something like this:

```
const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "cities", "SF"), (doc) => {
    unsub();
    // Use `doc` here, or call a function here to which you pass `doc`.
});
```

If however you were hoping to get access to `doc` right after the `onSnapshot` function returns, you're out of luck. The callback hasn't run yet, so `doc` isn't available yet.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot to solve all my questions. I will try to write a complete answer to my question based on your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. But maybe it will help you:

```
function func_a(callback:(arg:string)=>number){
  callback("callback arg")
  return "func_a return"
}

type Callback = Parameters<typeof func_a>[0]; // (arg:string)=>number
type ReturnCb = ReturnType<Callback>; // number
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=48&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSB9AhgCgugNrgI3QgGsAuTdAJwHMyBnKKmMGgSgF4A%20MEAWwIBTKmwDeAKESIc%20IqUwAiGYWIlE1GgraTEVQVBBUkClBAy79hsAvEBfceKgBPAA6DEAYTwrSiDogAFanQ%20fWF6AB5nNzhgZHAzdC4AbQAGAF0AbkQAehzESloGJhZ2bl4BYUdXdwAlSyMPAj9EeoMjABUaiK9ZVS5svMQKoSogA)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [tricot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73276321/14119317), all my questions have been solved. Here I will try to write a complete answer to my question based on the answer.

First of all, `onSnapshot` calls callback asynchronously. So for my `func_a` to simulate the behavior of `onSnapshot`, my first code example needs to be changed as follows.

```
function func_a(callback:(arg:string)=>void){
  setTimeout(
    callback.bind(null,"callback arg"),
    1000
  )
  return "func_a return"
}
```

Receiving both the callback function argument and the function return value outside of the function can be done with the following code.

```
type CallbackArgAndFunctionReturn={
  callback_arg:string,
  function_return:string
}

new Promise<CallbackArgAndFunctionReturn>(
  (resolve)=>{
    const func_a_return=func_a(
      (arg)=>resolve({
        callback_arg:arg,
        function_return:func_a_return
      })
    )
  }
).then((arg_return)=>{
  console.log(arg_return.callback_arg)
  console.log(arg_return.function_return)
})
```

Since the callback function is executed asynchronously after the function returns its value, the return value is available inside the callback function; this provided a way to get both of the values, from which I wrote the code above.

This allows me to do what I wanted to do with `onSnapshot`. For example, in React, I can separate the `unsubsribe` function and `snapshot` outside of `onSnapshot` as follows.

```
export default function Home(){
  const [myUnsubscribe,setMyUnsubscribe]=useState<Unsubscribe|undefined>()
  const GetCity=()=>new Promise<SnapshotUnsubscribe>((resolve)=>{
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, "cities", "SF"),
      (snapshot)=>resolve({ snapshot, unsubscribe })
    )
  })
  
  useEffect(
    ()=>{
      GetCity().then(({snapshot, unsubscribe})=>{
        setMyUnsubscribe(unsubscribe)
      })
      return ()=>{myUnsubscribe && myUnsubscribe()}
    },[]
  )

  return <div></div>
}
```

Next, I will also show an answer to my question about the first code example where the callback function is executed before the function returns a value.

Since the function returns the value after the callback function executed, the return value won't be assigned if resolved immediately in the callback function. Therefore, as shown in the following code, we should wait asynchronously in the callback function before resolve.

```
function func_a(callback:(arg:string)=>void){
  callback("callback arg")
  return "func_a return"
}

type CallbackArgAndFunctionReturn={
  callback_arg:string,
  function_return:string
}

new Promise<CallbackArgAndFunctionReturn>(
  (resolve)=>{
    const func_a_return=func_a((arg)=>{
      setTimeout(
        ()=>{
          resolve({
            callback_arg:arg,
            function_return:func_a_return
          })
        },
        1000)
    })
  }
).then((arg_return)=>{
  console.log(arg_return.callback_arg)
  console.log(arg_return.function_return)
})
```